Locale-aware number verification in Python?
I need to verify a string has a valid number format as opposed to a date (and random strings containing numbers)
I tried parsing the string using locale.atof(), expecting a ValueError on invalid inputs.
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')

valid = locale.atof('1.234.567,89')
invalid = locale.atof('31.10.2024')

Unfortunately, it appears like locale.atof() just removes any thousands separator, regardless of their position, so invalid is parsed to 31102024.0.
Is there a pythonic way to do locale-aware number parsing that doesn't accept mis-formated numbers?

Yes, 'atof()' only converts to float the result of delocalize() which basically removes all locale-specific characters.
I think you will have to go with a regex, and use the fullmatch() function: something like
from re import compile
regex = compile(r'(\d){1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?')
m = regex.fullmatch('12.345.678,90') #returns a Match object
m = regex.fullmatch('12.345678,90') #returns None
m = regex.fullmatch('31.10.2024') #returns None


I was hoping there was something in the standard library (like..dunno... "locale") that allowed me to check without having to hard-code a regex that's likely to break as soon as data from a different locale is used. Or any library, really.

I don't think there is anything in the standard lib. If you are going to use different locales perhaps you could programmatically build the regex accessing the settings of the current locale, e.g. with localeconv
